# apex chart with negative values

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I created a visualforce with apex:chart and apex:barSeries with stacked attribute set to true.
One of the values is negative and I want it to be under the x axis.
How do I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that there is no way to have the axis placed like that (e.g. here is an ExtJs chart including negative values https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5gq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another apex:barSeries only with the value which can be negative and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44017)

Comment: I am the author of the question and it provided an answer to my question ...